# Click the same cell a second time (toggle)

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, toggle

'EXCEL for Mac

Need 200 checkbox simulated but checkbox slows excel down.

Trying to toggle the same cell between two Custom values repeatedly.
As in clicking the same cell as second Time while active.

`Application.ontime` function does not work for me in the following code:
'I have allowed all Macros to execute.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Or Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Check if the value of the active cell matches cell A1
    If ActiveCell.Value <> Range("A1").Value Then
        ' Assign the active cell to cell A1
        ActiveCell.Value = Range("A1").Value
    Else
       ActiveCell.Value = Range("B1").Value
    End If

    ' Call the CheckActiveCellValue subroutine
    'CheckActiveCellValue
    
        ' To allow triggering the event even when clicking on the same cell,
    ' you can call the event manually using Application.OnTime
    
    
    
   ' WILL NOT WORK
    'Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "TriggerSelectionChangeX"
    'Application.OnTime TimeValue(Now() + TimeSerial(0, 1, 0)), "TriggerSelectionChangeX"

    
End Sub

Sub TriggerSelectionChangex()
    Worksheet_SelectionChange Selection
End Sub

Sub HelloWorld()

MsgBox "Hello World"
Application.OnTime TimeValue(Now() + TimeSerial(0, 1, 0)), "HelloWorld"

End Sub
```

In the example above after the first execution at 17:00, will repeat after every 1 minute.

This code does work for ticking my custom on and off checkbox graphics.
But I cant seem to click the same cell to toggle the value.
I've ticked on the Allow all Macros to execute setting.

Comment: As the name `Worksheet_SelectionChange` suggests, the selection needs to change for the event to be triggered again. If you click on the cell already selected, it won't do anything. You'd need to select another cell before you can toggle the value or you'd need to use another event such as `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` or even use a keyboard shortcut using `Application.OnKey`.

Comment: Also, depending on the version of Excel you have, you might have access to the new Excel checkboxes that are much lighter to use than the ActiveX ones: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNl9DzNwjv8

Comment: If you've answered your question, feel free to post an answer instead of a comment. You'll be able to format your code properly in an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic support.  Thanks braX for the edit. Thanks DecimalTurn  for the multiple replies.  Much apprecaited.  Im using Excel for Mac.  So a lot of features are not there.  I did try to use the CheckBox.  But using 200 slows excel down considerably.  I'll have to work out how the set focus on a cell that is off screen without the screen moving to the cell.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "A1" Or Target.Address = "B1" Or Target.Address = "C1" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If ActiveCell.Value = Range("A1").Value Or ActiveCell.Value = Range("B1").Value Then

         'Check if the value of the active cell matches cell A1
        If ActiveCell.Value <> Range("A1").Value Then
             'Assign the active cell to cell A1
            ActiveCell.Value = Range("A1").Value
        Else
           ActiveCell.Value = Range("B1").Value
        End If

   End If

   Range("C1").Select
     

 End Sub
```